# Function expansion in power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am trying to expand the function 
$f: \Bbb C \setminus\{ 1\} \to \Bbb C,  f(z):= \frac{1}{1-z}$ into a power series with center c = -1. That seems to me like the sum of a geometric serie for a $ |z| <1$. how should i shift the center? Can anybody help me with this example please. 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and subtract $1$ in the denominator $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{2-(z+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-(z+1)/2}$$

Then use that $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$ with $x=(z+1)/2$.